# Swift HTTP POST login validation

Tags: swift, authentication, swift3, http-post

Currently working on an iOS app where HTTP POST method is needed to communicate with the server. Getting the username and password if is correct or not is a success, but the server returns as string 
for example:

If correct username and password:

> <string> Correct </string>

if incorrect username or password:

> <string> Incorrect </string>

How can I add validation as in:
If the current username and password are correct go to the next ViewController, but if the current username or password is incorrect display an error message without going to next ViewController.

This is the code I am using:

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var passwordField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var usernameField: UITextField!


override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

           }

    @IBAction func LoginGetData(_ sender: Any) {


        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://mylinkinhere")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "username=\(usernameField.text!)&password=\(passwordField.text!)"
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

             let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus!.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
                print(postString)

            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("responseString = \(responseString)")

        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your API response is `application/xml` not the `application/json`, but for this response you can use `contains` and check is it correct or incorrect. So after getting response try like this.

```
let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
print("responseString = \(responseString)")

if (responseString?.contains("Incorrect")) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print("incorrect - try again")
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Try Again", message: "Username or Password Incorrect", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)                    
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))                                        
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}                
else {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print("correct good")

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "correctone")
        self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: @AmdAl-Haddad Welcome mate :)

Comment: @AmdAl-Haddad Don't get your above comment, Can you specify what detail you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Get the `<string> Correct </string>` value in String variable.

**USe this code when you get the response string.**

let str_Status = VALUEFROMstring

Now,

```
if self.Selected == "Correct"
{
   self.performSegueWithIdentifier("YOUR_SEGUE_IDENTIFIER_IN_STORYBOARD", sender: self)
}
else
{
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "UserName Password are incorrect.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        if handler == nil
        {
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        }
        else
        {
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: handler))
        }

        delegate.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please create a server `api` with data validation whether username and its relevant password matches or not and sends a response to every post with appropriate messages with inbuilt in keys then check the response and deliver it to the user as well.